# Number Theory problem mod 2p

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ be an odd prime, and let $a$ be an odd integer such that $p \nmid a .$ Prove that
$$
a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \quad(\bmod 2 p)
$$

I thought about Fermat Little Theorem could be useful but for that we need prime in modulo. But her we have 2p so it is an even integer. Can somebody give me hint for how to proceed?

Comment: Consider mod 2, then use the Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: $a^{p-1} = 1 mod2$ ; $a^{p-1} = 1 mod p$ then what @ParclyTaxel

Comment: @mathsstudent you have $2|a^{p-1}-1$ as well as $p|a^{p-1}-1$ and as $gcd(2,p)=1$ $2p|a^{p-1}-1$

Comment: ohh right Thanks @Shamim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $2|a^{p-1}-1$ and $p|a^{p-1}-1$ by fermat's little theorem, and as $gcd(2,p)=1$ you have $2p|a^{p-1}-1$ as well

Answer (score 1):

Since $a\in \mathbb Z_{2p}^*$ and $|\mathbb Z_{2p}^*|=\varphi(2p) = p-1$, then
\begin{equation}
a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \quad\bmod 2p
\end{equation}